# Delete all tables in the postgresql database using Django without deleting the database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, cloud

I am running AWS Elastic Beans which automatically set up a working postgresql database instance and connection for me. Therefore I do not want to just delete the database instance and configure it myself. I would rather just delete all tables in the database from python/django. I also do not want to delete the content of all tables (what `python manage.py flush` does).

I want the database to return to a state where I can just run `python manage.py migrate` and it will create all empty tables from my current model definitions.

Thanks

Comment: @IainShelvington yes, it does indeed, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Prints the SQL statements that would be executed for the flush command. Will delete all the data from tables in database

django-admin sqlflush

# You can pass the name of your database specifically. Defaults to default.

--database DATABASE

# If you want to delete all the tables of your app, then you can run the command

python manage.py migrate appname zero
```

Comment: I do not want to delete all data from the tables, I want to delete the tables themselves so that I could just run a fresh python manage.py migrate afterwards to get clean tables with my new (maybe changed) models.

Comment: python manage.py migrate appname zero - command will delete your table